# How can you create electricity from nano-scale heat flux?

Tags: thermodynamics, electricity, thermoelectricity

This article "[Engineers develop chip that converts wasted heat to usable energy](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/07/190710103145.htm)" on the Science Daily website states the following claim:

> ...findings were published in the paper,
>   A Near-Field Radiative Heat Transfer Device, in the newest issue of
>   Nature Nanotechnology.
>
> ...
>
> The team produced a 5mm-by-5mm chip ...
>   of two silicon wafers with a nanoscopic gap between them only 100
>   nanometers thick... While
>   the chip was in a vacuum, they heated one surface and cooled another
>   surface, which created a heat flux that can generate electricity.

So *my main question is, what is the fundamental physical principle that enables this to work?*

It also goes on to say,

> "Nobody can emit more radiation than the blackbody limit," he said.
>   "But when we go to the nanoscale, you can."

This seems like a contradictory statement (or just a too-casual description) but it would be interesting to understand what blackbody limit is being referred to in this context and how this silicon-wafer approach appears to evade the limit.

Comment: Have you researched blackbody radiation?

Comment: @SolarMike I remember some generalities from physics in college, that's about it.